# Makefile: multiple similar targets in directories

Tags: loops, makefile

Suppose I have a makefile like this:

```
main: modA.o modB.o modC.o
    g++ -o main modA.o modB.o modC.o

modA.o: $(path)/modA/modA.cpp
    g++ -c $(path)/modA/modA.cpp

modB.o: $(path)/modB/modB.cpp
    g++ -c $(path)/modB/modB.cpp

modC.o: $(path)/modC/modC.cpp
    g++ -c $(path)/modC/modC.cpp
```

where `modA`, `modB`, `modC` are small sub-instances of my program, that lie in $(path) and all are built the same way (as you see).

How can I make this more beautiful, like in a for loop over the list `modA modB modC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) with [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).  Also you should be using standard make variables.

```
CXX = g++

main: modA.o modB.o modC.o
        $(CXX) ?$(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $(path)/$$*/$$*.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```